# How to fix extended property on express request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a middleware in javascript where I can get the information of the user by using the famous "req" of the route handler.
When i do a console.log(currentUser), I get the expected value but the currentUser is giving a typescript error warning: Property 'currentUser' does not exist on type 'Request<{}, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)

Below is my piece of code:

middleware

```
const currentUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.cookies?.token) return next();

  try {
    const payload = jwt.verify(req.cookies.token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    req.currentUser = payload;
  } catch {}

  next();
};

exports.currentUser = currentUser;
```

currentUser

```
const { currentUser } = require("../middleware");

router.get("/users/currentuser", currentUser, (req, res) => {
  const { currentUser } = req;
  console.log(currentUser);
});

exports.currentUser = router;
```

and this is the result when I do the console.log:

{
id: '625c2298ec690d8db4c6b37d',
email: 'test@mail.com',
role: 'user',
name: 'Martin',
iat: 1650218344,
exp: 1650304744
}

Can some one help me out fixing this in javascript because i'm not familiar with typescript.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

The [Request](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req) type of Router contains some fixed properties.

If you want to add your own custom properties to it, either use

`req.currentUser = payload;`

OR

Create a type for own use like below, and use it for req

```
export type CustomRequest = ExpressRequest & {
  currentUser?: string | JwtPayload;
};
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

for this one you can use Type.

```
type NewRequest = Request & {
  currentUser: string | JwtPayload,
}

async (req:NewRequest, res:Response, next:NextFunction)
```

I Hope, this will help you. Thanks)